# Организация работы с веб-проектами клиентов через git (Bitbucket, GitHub)

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, проекты

Господа, большая просьба направить на правильный путь работы с проектами используя git (репозиторий bitbucket), или "разжевать" принцип работы.

У нас на данный момент примерно 30-40 клиентов на поддержке сайтов.
Работают 3 разработчика.
Работаем по старинке - пришла задача, кто-то взял в работу и просился сразу через ftp на боевом сайте работать. Контроля версий, песочниц и прочих плюшек современных разработчиков у нас нет.

Ужасно, согласен.

Часто бывает, при одновременной работе над одним проектом, случайно перезаписываем работы друг друга...

Очень хочется начать работать через git, иметь репозиторий и т.д.
Читали кучу статей, в т.ч. и pro git и т.д.

Так и не поняли схему работы. Как мы у себя могли бы применять схему работы через контроль версий...

Клиентов много, неужели нужно для каждого проекта клиента, разворачивать локальную копию сайта и работать с ней??

Не совсем понятно этапы работы, т.к. что после чего следует, что является первоисточником и т.д.?

Первоисточник это репозиторий? Дальше работы ведутся в песочнице на локальном компьютере, отправляются в репозиторий и оттуда на боевой сайт? Или как? опишите пожалуйста подробно, как это бывает? Т.е. очень сложно из книг и статей приложить на практику.

Неужели такая сложная схема работы? Если правки  на сайте (работы на 5 мин), то нужно сначала их сделать в песочнице, потом залить в репозиторий, потом на боевой сайт? Это в 2-3 раза увеличивает время работ над задачами..
Еще и нужно учитывать актуальность БД в песочнице и на боевом сайте..

Как работают другие веб-студии?

Comment: "Как работают другие веб-студии?" Не так )

Comment: "Это в 2-3 раза увеличивает время работ над задачами" - зато в 10 уменьшает время поиска причины (и "источника") поломки сайта.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "первоисточником"?

Comment: "Это в 2-3 раза увеличивает время работ над задачами" - если все автоматизировать, то никак не в 2-3 раза (разве что задачи минутные). Но любой процесс так или иначе замедляет работу. Главное при этом получить и прирост качества.